# JSON Serde - Mapping Column Names

Tags: json, hadoop, hive

I'm using the JSON-Serde feature of mapping columns to rename a column I have in my json document 'Customer ID' -> 'customer_id. The reason why I'm using the mapping function is because HQL doesn't allow spaces in the CREATE TABLE definition.

The json document looks like this:

```
{"browser":"Safari",
"device_uuid":"gftgbvnfg-ed1ae6de-e2df-11e1-4c20-00ef75f32667",
"custom":    
     {"Customer ID":"4985495}"
}
```

The create table hive is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE json_serde_test
(
    browser        STRING,
    device_uuid    STRING,
    custom         struct< customer_id : STRING >
)

ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ('json.mappings' = 'custom.Customer ID:custom.customer_id')
STORED AS TEXTFILE;
```

When I try and query the json_serde_test table, the custom field returns:

```
{"customer_id":null}
```

Answer (score 7):

Note: I am the author of the SerDe. 
Editing the answer since I first answered just from memory and it was incorrect.
This one will work (tested)

```
CREATE TABLE json_serde_test
(
    browser        STRING,
    device_uuid    STRING,
    custom         struct< customer_id : STRING >
)

ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ('mapping.customer_id' = 'Customer ID')
STORED AS TEXTFILE;

LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH 'data.txt' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE json_serde_test;
```

The mapping should have the form of: mapping.*hive column*=*json column*

I tested it and it works as it should:

```
hive> select custom from json_serde_test;
OK
{"customer_id":"4985495}"}
```

Comment: How do I map hive column to nested JSON keys?

Eg: does the following "path" work?
"mapping.id" = "products[1].id"

Comment: No, that would not work, but for that kind of things you can still create a view on top of the table.