# AWS Athena -- Changing a column name when reading it in

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I have data sitting in an S3 bucket that was collected by an outside source. One of the columns is `publish date`, which is problematic because Athena doesn't know what to do with it.

I've tried a few obvious things, like wrapping the column name in double ("publish date") or single ('publish date') quotes, but I'm still just getting an empty column in the database created from the S3 files.

Is there a way to rename a column *as* it's being read in?

EDIT -- I eventually found this, which was exactly what I was looking for: [JSON Serde - Mapping Column Names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30002399/json-serde-mapping-column-names)

Comment: What is the format of your data, e.g csv, json etc? Also, could you provide with DDL statement of your table, i.e `SHOW CREATE TABLE ...`

Comment: You need to post details in particular i.e, file format, sample records so that you can get faster answers

Comment: Thanks @bdcloud for the advice.